How is 'character quality' calculated?
In Rimworld, prisoners have their 'character quality' shown when
hovering the mouse on the 'slave price' entry in the 'Prisoner' tab.
I am curious about what affects 'character quality'. By observation, I
have concluded two patterns so far:

Health conditions would affect 'character quality'. People with worse health condition
would have smaller 'character quality'.
Pawn trait would affect 'character quality'. People with trait 'Inventor' would have
larger 'character quality'.

I want to to find more detailed information about how is 'character quality'
calculated, but I didn't succeed.
I have read the 'Prisoners' page in the wiki,
but it didn't mention 'character quality'.
I think the DLCs might affect the calculation, but I am not sure,
since I am only on the base version, without any mods and DLCs.

The short answer:
It's complicated
The wiki page with most of the info you're looking for is actually at Market Value

The simple formula for Pawns is:
Base Value x Quality Multiplier + Price offset
Base Value
This is simple -- for humans, it's $1750.
Quality Multiplier
This is the most complicated factor. It covers both health (e.g. a pawn with a damaged arm is worth less than a pawn with a working arm), skill (e.g. a pawn with 0 in Plants is worth less than one with 20 in Plants), and capability (e.g. a pawn on luciferium is worth more, because their Manipulation and Consciousness stats are higher).
Traits are included in this, as well as beauty (which some traits effect). The full list, as far as I know, is:

Staggeringly Ugly / Ugly / Pretty / Beautiful (Indirectly, from Beauty)
Chemical Interest / Chemical Fascination
Abrasive
Wimp
Annoying Voice
Pyromaniac

Price Offset
The simplest way to think of this part is "weapons + clothing" -- essentially anything the Pawn has equipped, though this also includes removable parts, both natural organs (Lungs, Heart, etc.), and Bionics.
